# $\sin(x)$ infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, infinite-product

In the equation:
$$\sin(x) =  x\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right),$$

I know that if I set 
$$0 = x\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right),$$

all of the roots are really going to be the roots of $\sin(x)$. But why is this generally **equal** to $\sin(x)$? How can I know that $\sin(2.285672364)$ will be $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{(2.285672364)^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$, for example? 
(I mean, how do I know that the graphs of both functions will be the same?).

How can I assume that the coefficients of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ in the **product** expansion are going to be the same of the **sum** expansion, i.e. in the Taylor series? $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!} + \cdots\right)$ like **Euler** showed in the 'Basel problem', by saying:
$$\frac{x^2}{3!} = \frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots\right)$$
So: $$\zeta(2) = \frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + ... = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: You take the logarithmic derivative and see that it gives you the partial fraction decomposition of the cotangent (which again involves some work determining that what you get is actually the partial fraction decomposition of the cotangent).

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Product_representations_of_functions) may help you.